# Difference in boolean indexing depending on indexing notation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm experiencing something weird in pandas and trying to figure out why. I created a new column based on a simple if/else function applied on an age column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/04_Apply/Students_Alcohol_Consumption/student-mat.csv')

def majority(x):
    if x >= 18:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['legal_drinker'] = df.age.apply(majority)
```

But now, depending on how I index, I get two different answers:

```
df[df['legal_drinker'] == True].shape
    >>(111, 13)

df[df.legal_drinker == True].shape`
    >>(1, 13)
```

Anybody know why this could be? It's totally perplexing me.

Pic for reference: [image]

Comment: What version of `pandas`, I cannot replicate your issue both are the same shape `(111, 34)` for me.

Comment: I could not replicate your results either with the given code.  Are you doing something else between the assignment of legal_drinker and shape commands?

Comment: Try restarting/clearing your kernel. I'd like to see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify `majority` to be just `def majority(x): return x >= 18`